# How to deploy multiple flask application on Amazon Lambda by Zappa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

I have a bunch of applications interact each other.
I need to deploy them on Amazon Lambda, each app will have each domain.
I am deploying them with zappa. After I deploy one, just tried to deploy another one. But I am getting this error.

> Error: This application is already deployed - did you mean to call
>   update?

It seems it's going to update already deployed previous application. 
I have no idea about this. Why are they recognized as same application?
Do you have any idea about this? How I can deploy it as independent services on Lambda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lambda functions that are created by Zappa will be named based on the name of the stage and the project_name in your zappa_settings.json So the following settings:

```
{
 # Stage name
 "production": {
    # Project name
    "project_name": "task"
 }
}
```

will yield a lambda function named "task-production". You can use the combination of project name and stage name to create unique names for you lambda function deployments and manage them individually.